# Side-by-side config error: developer fix?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, side-by-side

I am a schoolteacher, and I wrote a demo program intending to let my students use it. But when run on school laptops I got,

> "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side
>   configuration is incorrect"

Now I've read about several solutions for dealing with this error message **as a user**. They involve editing the registry. And realistically, in our school IT environment, that change will not be feasible. So I want to know, is there something I can do to help this problem **as the developer**?

BTW, an executable I built more than 10 years ago is loading and running just fine, it's not a problem with security on the computers. It's a bug.

Development system: Windows 7 64 bit, Visual C++ 2005

Target computers: HP laptop, Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: use [sxstrace](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875651.aspx) to analyze the issue

Comment: Is there an application manifest? (Either a separate file or built into the EXE). If so, it will list its dependencies - possibly some DLL referenced there is not being installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18471).